# what do people use for incoming email in rails 3 for multi accounts applications?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email

what do people use for incoming email in rails 3 for multi accounts applications ?

It seems like actionmailer just uses one account to send and receive from ?

Look forward to your feedback.

Thanks
Rick

Answer (score 3):

have a look at http://cloudmailin.com/

Answer (score 1):

[Procmail](http://www.procmail.org/) with a small handler script to load the email contents into the database.  Procmail is universal, simple, and pretty much unbreakable for this sort of job.